# AS3 - question about symbol binding

Tags: actionscript-3, binding, scope, anonymous-function

I'm new to AS3, and can't figure out why this loop isn't behaving the way it "should."

```
for each (var s in [_set, _set.otherSet]) {
  for each (var f in [s.frame_top_mc, s.frame_bottom_mc]) {
    f.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function( ):void {
      _score[f.category] += 1;
      madeSelection(f);
    });
  }
}
```

How can I give each anonymous function a reference to each object represented by `f`, rather than a simple reference to `f` each time?

Specifically, why is it that each copy of the anonymous function gets bound to a single reference to `f`?  How (I should say why) exactly does AS3 differ from JavaScript in this regard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to be like this:

```
for each (var s in [_set, _set.otherSet]) {
  for each (var f in [s.frame_top_mc, s.frame_bottom_mc]) {
    f.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function( e:MouseEvent ):void {
      _score[e.currentTarget.category] += 1;
      madeSelection(e.currentTarget);
    });
  }
}
```

The problem is that your closure is closing over the loop variable **f** itself rather than each thing f is being used to reference within the loop. After the loop completes, **f** is left as reference to the last thing in the list you looped over. **f** is not being de-referenced when the closure is created, but when it's executed.

Comment: I knew that was probably the case - didn't know how to circumvent it though.  Thanks!